# Ektron Error after Uploading PDF and Folder Sync

Tags: pdf, synchronization, ektron

After uploading a PDF to the database and performing a sync on a specific folder, we received an error when a user tries to view the uploaded PDF in a page.

If we do a whole database sync, this error goes away.

When uploading PDFs, do we have to use the whole database sync for PDFs or is using a folder sync fine?

We're using version 9.00 SP2 (build 9.0.0.249).

Comment: A folder sync should be fine. Have you synced with any other systems? Tested locally with the same version? Might be a product problem (go to Support) or might be a problem with that specific configuration. Have you checked whether the file actually makes it across? What is the error? etc.

Comment: We have not synced with other systems. We did test locally and received the same error. The file does in fact make it across but for some reason Ekrton just can'e "see" it after a folder sync. I have brought this issue up on the Ektron Developer forum but have not gotten any responses. As for the error, i cannot remember what it was but can try and recreate it and add it to the post.

Comment: I'd like to know the error. Plus, there may be a more detailed error put into the Event Viewer.

Comment: By the way, I get email notifications from the Developer Forum, but only in the For Developers section. Apologies if yours went unnoticed.

Comment: Not a problem, it was a few months back. I am getting the error message for you to look at now